# How to convert List<IEnumerable<ProductViewModel>> into <IEnumerable<ProductViewModel>>?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I am accessing data from a Category's `ICollection<Product> Products` property. If you look at my controller code below, using the second select, I change each product's `Form` from a Product entity into a ProductViewModel which returns an `IQueryable<IEnumerable<ProductViewModel>>`.

Finally, with the `ToListAsync()` method, the model returns a `List<IEnumerable<ProductViewModel>>` which is not accepted by my `View`.

My controllers model is this:

```
var model = (await db.Categories.Where(c => c.Id == id).Select(p => p.Products.Select(x => new 
                    ProductViewModel { Id = x.Id, Name = x.Name,  ByteImage = x.Image, Price = x.Price})).ToListAsync());

            return View(model);
```

The return type for this model is `List<IEnumerable<ProductViewModel>>` and I cannot iterate through this model inside my View to display the data.

View model given to the `View` is:

`@model IEnumerable<ProductViewModel>`.

This is the error message I get:

> Compiler Error Message: CS0411: The type arguments for method 'DisplayNameExtensions.DisplayNameFor(HtmlHelper, Expression>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

```
Source Error:

Line 14:     <tr>
Line 15:         <th>
Line 16:             @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
Line 17:             
Line 18:         </th>
```

ProductViewModel:

```
public class ProductViewModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required, Display(Name="Product Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Required, DataType(DataType.Upload)]
        public HttpPostedFileBase Image { get; set; }
        public string OutputImage { get; set; }
        public Byte[] ByteImage { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public Decimal Price { get; set; }

        public static byte[] ConvertToByte(ProductViewModel model)
        {
            if (model.Image != null)
            {
                byte[] imageByte = null;
                BinaryReader rdr = new BinaryReader(model.Image.InputStream);
                imageByte = rdr.ReadBytes((int)model.Image.ContentLength);

                return imageByte;
            }

            return null;
        }

        // ViewModel => Model | Implicit type Operator
        public static implicit operator Product(ProductViewModel viewModel)
        {
            var model = new Product
            {
                Id = viewModel.Id,
                Name = viewModel.Name,
                Image = ConvertToByte(viewModel),
                Price = viewModel.Price
            };

            return model;
        }

        // Model => ViewModel | Implicit type Operator
        public static implicit operator ProductViewModel(Product model)
        {
            var viewModel = new ProductViewModel
            {
                Id = model.Id,
                Name = model.Name,
                OutputImage = string.Format("data:image/jpg;base64,{0}", Convert.ToBase64String(model.Image)),
                Price = model.Price
            };

            return viewModel;
        }

    }
```

This is the View Index:

```
@model List<ValueVille.Models.ProductViewModel>
@using MvcApplication8.Models

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)

        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Image)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Price)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Image)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Price)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.Id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.Id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.Id })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

Comment: Looks like you just want to use `model.SelectMany(x => x)` to flatten out the results.

Comment: I really haven't absorbed the meat of your question. But a quick fix would be to change the first `.Select()` to `.SelectMany()` in your LINQ.

Comment: Thank you for that.

Comment: Do you get IneliiSense support when you type `model.Name`?

Comment: Yes, but I get a bunch of collection methods and no access to object properties directly.

Comment: Are you iterating over `Model`?

Comment: I am, further below in the View. I've added the View above

Comment: Thanks so much for your help bro! :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use `SelectMany` instead:

```
(await db.Categories
         .Where(c => c.Id == id)
         .SelectMany(p => p.Products.Select(x => new ProductViewModel { Id = x.Id, Name = x.Name, ByteImage = x.Image, Price = x.Price }))
         .ToListAsync());
```

`SelectMany` is useful when you want to project from multiple sequences into a single (flat) sequence.

---

As per your update:

Since your model is actually `List<ProductViewModel>`, when you want to display the name of certain property, you need to point to an actual `ProductViewModel` instance *within* that list.

For example:

```
@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model[0].Name)
```

See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548748(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thank you for that. I now get a List<ProductViewModel> returned from the controller and the View seems to have red underline errors with the `@Html.DisplayNameFor()` and `Html.DisplayFor()` tag helpers. Is there list specific tag helpers I need to use?

Comment: @Naz786, Show your `ProductViewModel`

Comment: I've just included it above.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, you sequence looks like this

```
[ [model1, model2, model3], [model4, model] ]
```

to flatten it you could

```
model.SelectMany(m => m)
```

for

```
[ model1, model2, model3, model4, model5 ]
```

(if that's really what you want)

Comment: I am accessing data with the request `product/index/[Category ID]` and all product objects specific to that category should be displayed with the query.